# How do you change an URL from something.php?var=val to something more readable/friendly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure what this is called, but I've tagged it mod-rewrite and .htaccess since a couple similar questions are in these categories.

All pages I have end in .php, how can I change it such that the extension is removed and general URL rewriting to be more friendly/readable?

A specific example is an item page where there are links to items in the form `/dir/page.php?itemno=val`, where `val` comes from a database and the text I'd like to replace it comes from the table `val` is stored in.

```
$getNames = $db->prepare("
    SELECT val, name
        FROM items
");
$getNames->execute();
```

The result set might look like:

```
val | name
 1  | john
 2  | bill
 3  | anna
 4  | tomm
 5  | sara
... | ...
```

How can I rewrite the URL such that the below happens?

```
/dir/page.php?itemno=1 becomes /dir/page/john/
/dir/page.php?itemno=2 becomes /dir/page/bill/
/dir/page.php?itemno=3 becomes /dir/page/anna/
...
```

The result set is small enough (20 values) that I could hardcode it instead of grabbing from SQL, but just how to rewrite urls escapes me. I'm not sure how it's done.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` rules are done by the webserver (apache) and cannot access values in the database.  You *can* make the URL `/dir/page/john/`, but then you'd have to look up the ID in the database (I'm assuming there are not any duplicate names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this with `mod_rewrite`, the only caveat is that Apache (or whatever web server) cannot access the database, so you'll have to look up the `itemno` in each request.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /dir/page/(.*) /dir/page.php?itemno=$1 [L]
```

Now going to `/dir/page/john` will actually load up `/dir/page.php?itemno=john`.